# Handlebar and Safari 9 issue

Tags: javascript, safari, coffeescript, handlebars.js

My code in .handlebar file is as:

```
<div class='module-sequence-padding'></div>
<div class='module-sequence-footer clearfix'>
  <div class="module-sequence-footer-content">
    {{#if previous.show}}
      <a href="{{previous.url}}" role="button" class="pull-left" data-tooltip="right" data-html-tooltip-title="{{previous.tooltip}}" aria-describedby="msf{{instanceNumber}}-previous-desc">
        <i class="icon-mini-arrow-left"></i>{{#t 'previous'}}Previous{{/t}}
        <span id="msf{{instanceNumber}}-previous-desc" class="hidden" hidden>{{previous.tooltipText}}</span>
      </a>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if next.show}}
      <a href="{{next.url}}" role="button" class="pull-right bordered" data-tooltip="left" data-html-tooltip-title="{{next.tooltip}}" aria-describedby="msf{{instanceNumber}}-next-desc">
        {{#t 'next'}}Next{{/t}}<i class="icon-mini-arrow-right"></i>
        <span id="msf{{instanceNumber}}-next-desc" class="hidden" hidden>{{next.tooltipText}}</span>
      </a>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is displayed in Chrome but not on Safari.

On Safari I am getting error as `RangeError: Invalid Date` for the following code:

```
  delivery = ajax({
    url: options.deliveryUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    global: false, # don't whine to the user if this fails
    headers: JSON_HEADERS,
    data: JSON.stringify({
      quiz_submission_events: eventSet.toJSON()
    })
  })
```

Can someone please help.